# setValidators is not working if the validation pattern is assigned dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular6, angular2-forms

I have some function where i m assigning validation dynamically

```
// set validation from sports response.
  private static setValidation(sportsItem: SportsFormResponse, sportsForm: FormGroup): void {
    const validationTypes: ValidatorFn[] = [];
    // if regex pattern got from questionnaire response.
    if (sportsItem.validation) {
      validationTypes.push(Validators.pattern(sportsItem.validation));
    }
    // if sportsItem is required true.
    if (this.checkBooleanPropertyExistForValidation(sportsItem.isRequired) === true) {
      validationTypes.push(Validators.required);
    }
    if (validationTypes.length > 0) {
      sportsForm.controls[sportsItem.questionId]
        .setValidators(validationTypes);
    }
  }
```

and i m getting response like this

```
{
      "sportsId": 5473,
      "label": "FVC",
      "answerValue": null,
      "answerCode": null,
      "sportsTypeId": 9,
      "lookupTypeId": null,
      "validation": "^(8\\\\.[0-5]|(0\\\\.0[1-9]|0\\\\.[1-9]([0-9]?)|[1-7]\\\\.[0-9]{1,2}|8\\\\.(?:[0-4][0-9]|50)))$",
      "validationMessage": "{“Please provide a valid result for the predicted FVC. This should be between 0.01 - 8.50"}",
      "sportsCode": "R94",
      "helperText": null,
      "isReadOnly": false,
      "isRequired": true,
      "cssClass": null
    },
```

here what happens when i hardcode value and put in this function then it works fine

```
if (sportsItem.validation) {
          validationTypes.push(Validators.pattern("^(8\\\\.[0-5]|(0\\\\.0[1-9]|0\\\\.[1-9]([0-9]?)|[1-7]\\\\.[0-9]{1,2}|8\\\\.(?:[0-4][0-9]|50)))$"));
        } 

but when its being assigned dyncmaiclly, validation doesnt work.

if (sportsItem.validation) {
          validationTypes.push(Validators.pattern(sportsItem.validation));
        }
```

i have debugged that the string(sportsItem.validation) is coming perfectly fine.
    i m not sure whats the problem with dynamic validation insertion.

**Can anyone please give me a hint for this?**

Answer (score 1):

I have added your code in stackblitz example and it is working in that example. I have taken only one formControl for that. i have passed the regex which accepts the alphabets only. You can try this example with your mentioned regex.

I have passed (keyup)="onInputChange()" in the input Html like this:

```
 <input type="text" formControlName="userName" class="form-control" (keyup)="onInputChange()" />
```

And added this method in ts file like this:

```
onInputChange() {
    console.log("onInputChange Called");
    this.setValidation("^[A-Za-z]+$", this.userFormGroup)
  }
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yzgp81?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpattern-add.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is originating from escape sequences in the regex pattern. if your backend is sending `\\\\` as a subset of pattern string in JSON and somewhere in your code this response gets transformed by `JSON.parse` it is converted to `\\` because `JSON.parse` treats that sequence as an escape sequence just like regex. Eventually it matches one backslash where you expect two.

So, changing;

`validationTypes.push(Validators.pattern(sportsItem.validation));`

into

`validationTypes.push(Validators.pattern(sportsItem.validation.replace(/\\/g, "\\\\")));`

might solve your problem.

i tested different combinations in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-99n4hb) but it is a bit ambigious because when imitating JSON response in editor, escape sequences are handled in three levels; string escape sequences, JSON escape sequences and RegExp escape sequences. So it is hard to reproduce exactly the same issue but it gives an idea of what is going on.

Comment: This did not work.:(
Currenlty i m doing this, but in some scenario it is still failing
 `
const decimal = sportsItem.validation.search('.d');
      if (decimal !== -1) {
        pattern = questionnaireItem.validation.replace(/\\/g, '');
        pattern = pattern.replace(/d/g, '\\d');
      } else {
        pattern = sportsItem.validation.replace(/\\/g, '');
      }
      validationTypes.push(Validators.pattern(pattern));`

Comment: what are you trying to match with the regex. `questionnaireItem.validation.replace(/\\/g, '')` this deletes all backslashes.  `pattern.replace(/d/g, '\\d')` this replaces all `d` chars with `\d` `sportsItem.validation.replace(/\\/g, '')` this also removes all backslashes. these doesn't make sense to me, i don't understand what you are trying to achieve with these regex.